# Safari Push Notifications - Add intermediate certificate to push package signature in Java

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications, bouncycastle

I am currently trying to compute the signature required for safari push notifications. This was working until apple changed the signing rules:

> Important: After February 14, 2016, you will need to sign the push package >with both the web push certificate and the intermediate certificate. The >updated create_signature function in the attached createPushPackage.php >companion file processes both certificates.

I have been using the BouncyCastle library to implement the this using a CMSSignedDataGenerator. This worked fine for the .p12 web push notification certificate. Now I have the AppleWWDRCA.pem intermediate certificate (converted from AppleWWDRCA.cer) and I have been trying to add the certificate to the existing signed data generator:

```
CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
```

Using:

```
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate appleCert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/AppleWWDRCA.pem"));
        JcaCertStore jcaCertStoreApple = new JcaCertStore(Collections.singleton(appleCert));
        generator.addCertificates(jcaCertStoreApple);
```

Why is this still giving me the "Signature verification of push package failed." error message?

Comment: The code seems okay; I'd guess the intermediate certificate is not. Did you notice that there was a cert expiry for the previous intermediate certificate on Feb 14, 2016? (https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration). Double-check that you have the latest, anyway. If that's not the issue, you could try verifying the generated CMSSignedData yourself and see if that turns up any errors.

Comment: I generated a new web push certificate and now it signs correctly.

Comment: What's the version of Bouncy castle that you used?